# Launch screens may not have triggered segues. (LaunchScreen.storyboard)

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder

I'm a beginner of Swift and XCode. When I tried to establish connection between a button and a "showMessage" method as is described in this [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/learnswift/build-your-first-app.html), the "showMessage" method cannot be found in the pop-up menu.

Then I downloaded the [code zip](http://www.appcoda.com/resources/swift3/HelloWorld.zip) of the tutorial, and run it in XCode. I got error:

- "Launch screens may not have triggered segues. (LaunchScreen.storyboard)"

The error storyboard is a main storyboard, not a launchscreen storyboard. Someone may have this trouble because he unintentionally checks "Use as launch screen" for a main storyboard. However, it's not checked in this case.

Where is wrong and how to fix it?

P.S. My XCode version is 8.2.1.

Comment: There is no error for me to run the zip source code.

Comment: Did you add any segue to the initial view controller of LaunchScreen.storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can not segue through the LaunchScreen.storyboard. Make it through Main.storyboard.[image: Select Main.storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

Set one:

check for Use as Launch Screen

[image: 1]

and uncheck "Use as Launch Screen"

[image: 2]

Set TWo:

```
check for Is Initial View Controller
```

[image: 3]

```
and uncheck "Is Initial View Controller"
```

[image: 4]

Set Three:

run your project again.

Comment: Please explain why these steps help.